# Symfony2: Doctrine's query allocates ridiculous amount of memory

Tags: php, performance, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am doing filtering with Doctrine's queryBuilder, which returns about 80k records. I select only three fields (two IDs for two joined entities and one string, which is string with length=255 (never that long, usually about 30-40 chars). I use `getArrayResult()`.

```
$filterResult = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('Bundle:Entity')
    ->createQueryBuilder('alias')
    -> // selects, joins, wheres
    ->getArrayResult();
```

I understand it may take some time to execute, because of some joins etc., but I noticed that after executing and saving the result to a variable (array, 80k records, each is array of 3: id/id/name) the memory consumed is about **70MB bigger**.

I checked it practically line by line, and nothing before sending query (creating query builder, processing form to build filter) increases memory significantly.

This is weird, because when in another place I save only one column to simple array with

```
$idsOnly = array_column($filterResult, "id"); // 80k of IDs
```

It takes about 4MB.

Now, what I tried (on `prod` environment of course):
 - `logging` and `profiling` for `doctrine.dbal` set to false in `config.yml` (nothing in `config_prod.yml` so I assume it stays on `prod`)
 - `$this->getDoctrine()->getConnection()->getConfiguration()->setSQLLogger(null);` in Controller's filtering action at the top
 - `$filterResult = null;`, then `gc_collect_cycles()`
 - `$em->clear()` and `gc_collect_cycles()` practically everywhere I could

And nothing changed. From my point of view, either multidimensional arrays take so much space or Doctrine leaves some garbage when fetching results from DB. What else should I try, except for NativeSQL?

Comment: Just to declare the array where, each entry is an array of three entries of integers,  will use about 32 MB. i.e. https://eval.in/654307. Each variable in PHP occupies about 144 bytes ;-/ This is PHP and nothing to do with Doctrine.

Comment: You're right... But when I changed from queryBuilder to raw SQL, it now uses half of the memory overall, which suggest Doctrine has something to explain to me! :)

Comment: Well, if it is only an extra 35MB it is probably understandable, doctrine adds an extra layer as you know above mysql and has to translate the query builder synthax to an actual query and (I think) receive the actual results...